# Django debug toolbar - java error cannot find djdt

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

in console I am seeing the error below for debug toolbar:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: djdt
Global Code — toolbar.js:306
```

I have everything setup as per https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

It did work but all of sudden no longer is and I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything to turn it off.

anyone else come across this one?

Thanks

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    ... 
    'storages',
    'imagekit',
    'django_celery_results',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'simple_history',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
]
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1')

def show_toolbar(request):
    return True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'JQUERY_URL':'',
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK" : show_toolbar,
}
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: Note your `INTERNAL_IPS` is missing a trailing comma to make it a tuple.

Comment: Hi, I've added the comma, cleared caches, and loaded in a diff browser too, and the error is still there, I also tried upgrading debug tool bar too incase there were errors in the install

Comment: Which version of debug toolbar are you using? Sound like the same issue Alasdair mentioned

Comment: django-debug-toolbar==1.11 ive cleared all caches and tried a few browsers to double check its not that, still same issue

Comment: The [`toolbar.js`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/blob/1.11/debug_toolbar/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js#L306) for 1.11 does not contain `djdt` so not give that error. Perhaps you forgot to update your static files (e.g. by running `collectstatic`).

Comment: @Alasdair that was it! I need to re un collect static to get it working again! thank you!